# check whether a session cookie is still alive (Python)

Tags: python, session-cookies, urllib, cookiejar, cookielib

Please take a look at the following  **python** code snippet :

```
import cookielib, urllib, urllib2

def login(username, password):
    cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    login = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password})
    try:
        login_data = opener.open("http://www.example.com/login.php", login).read()
    except IOError:
        return 'Network Error'

    # on successful login the I'm storing the 'SESSION COOKIE'
    # that the site sends on a local file called cookie.txt

    cookie_jar.save('./cookie.txt', True, True)
    return login_data

# this method is called after quite sometime
# from calling the above method "login" 

def re_accessing_the _site():
    cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

    # Here I'm re-loading the saved cookie
    # from the file to the cookie jar

    cookie_jar.revert('./cookie.txt', True, True)

    # there's only 1 cookie in the cookie jar
    for Cookie in cookie_jar:
        print 'Expires : ', Cookie.expires  ## prints None
        print 'Discard : ', Cookie.discard  ## prints True , means that the cookie is a
                                            ## session cookie
        print 'Is Expired : ', Cookie.is_expired()  ## prints False

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
    try:
        data = opener.open("http://www.example.com/send.php")

        # Sometimes the opening fails as the cookie has expired
        # & sometimes it doesn't. Here I want a way to determine
        # whether the (session) cookie is still alive

    except IOError:
        return False
    return True
```

First I'm calling the method **login** & saves the retrieved cookie (which is a **session cookie**)to a local file called **cookie.txt**.
Next after quite sometime (*15-20 mins*) I'm calling the other method **re_accessing_the _site** . This time I'm also re loading the previously saved cookie into the cookie jar.
Sometimes it's working fine but sometimes it's blocking me to access (**as the session cookie has expired**) . So all I need is a way to check whether the cookie is still alive during the call ...

Comment: It's possible that the timestamp of the authentication is in the data in the cookie, or even held server-side. In which case there may be no way to know by interrogating the Cookie object. If this is the case then you'll just have to cache the username/password yourself, catch the error, log in again and retry.

Just out of interest, can you paste Cookie.__dict__ in here as it might have more useful info somewhere...